# Need to use if instead of JavaScript to hide/show Input fields

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form that contains a Select field with two categories: `category1` and `category 2`. And fields `name`, `email`, `husband's name`, `password` etc..

I want the `husband's name` field to be hidden and that it will only be displayed if `category 1` is selected. And I would like this to be done using the `if condition` in this `husband's name` field without using JavaScript. can you help me do this please?

This is the code:

```html
<form role="form" action="patient/addNew" class="clearfix" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('categorie'); ?></label>
      <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="categorie" value=''>
         <option value="F#" > Sélectionner une catégorie </option>
         <option value="Cateory1" <?php
            if (!empty($patient->categorie)) {
                if ($patient->categorie == 'cateory1') {
                    echo 'selected';
                }
            }
            ?> > Cateory 1 </option>
         <option value="Categgory2" <?php
            if (!empty($patient->categorie)) {
                if ($patient->categorie == 'cateory2') {
                    echo 'selected';
                }
            }
            ?> > Cateorie 2 </option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('name'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('email'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('name_husband'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_husband" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('password'); ?></label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('address'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('andtecedentMed'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentMed" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('andtecedentFam'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentFam" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('taille'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taille" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
</form>
```

### Conclusion

**I want two things:**

1. that the `husband's name` field be hidden.
2. and this can only be displayed if `category 1` is selected.

Answer (score 2):

To remove an element completely you would need to use JavaScript.

You can use this simple CSS snippet to show `name_husband` conditionally, when `Category1` is selected using the `:checked` pseudo class.

```css
    form .form-group:has(input[name="name_husband"]) {
        display: none;
    }

    form:has(option[value="Category1"]:checked) .form-group:has(input[name="name_husband"]) { 
        display: block;
    }
```

It's also possible in this way, albeit more expensive, it is shorter and more straightforward:

```css
    form:has(option[value="Category1"]:not(:checked)) .form-group:has(input[name="name_husband"]) { 
        display: none;
    }
```

**notice:** I would preferably select the elements by setting a class on each rather than using their attribute selectors. However, I kept it as is so that it would work with your code.